# Is it possible to send terraform output data to particular column of existinf csv file

Tags: azure, terraform, output, export-to-csv

I have a set of data which I fetched from *terraform output*. I have sent the output to a csv file. But my requirement is to send the data to a particular column of an existing csv.

This is my code

```
data "azurerm_resources" "spokes" {
  type = "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
}

locals {
  vnetnames = ([for vnets in lookup(data.azurerm_resources.spokes, "resources", []) : lookup(vnets, "name")])
}

output "localvar" {
  value = join("\n", local.vnetnames)
}
```

What changes has to done to achieve the below expected output

[image]
This is how my output is sent

I need it to be in the below format where the data has to be sent column C which already has headers
[image]

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. How does your `data "azurerm_resources" "spokes"` relate to the excel file?

Comment: azurerm_resources will return a list of values which are stored in vnetnames. I need to export those values to CSV to a particular column. Also to note that first row consists of headers hence the values should get exported to second row, third column (C2)